# Not getting correct results from KeywordQuery search by UniqueID

Tags: sharepoint-search, keywordquery

This happens in code and also using the latest SharePoint Search Query Tool (v2.8.8, https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/releases/tag/v2.8.8-Search-QueryTool)

I do a query (Example "UniqueId:"{67286CE0-AA7C-4779-B220-9241FDB17C19}"" and it retrieves the file with that ID. I do another query for a different file with the correct UniqueID, and the ResultTable Row count is zero.

Is anyone else having a similar issue? It seems to be happening on several document libraries in my tenant. I can't find a patter as to the files it can't find. Some have been there for a while, some are new, and some a recently updated.

Searching by UI on the site seems to retrieve them, although at that point I'm not specifying UniqueID, just entering the guid in the search box.

Comment: Issue seems to be that for some files, including brackets in search is required;  in others, it does not work. 

So, for one file, "UniqueId:"{67286CE0-AA7C-4779-B220-9241FDB17C19}"" will work but "UniqueId:"67286CE0-AA7C-4779-B220-9241FDB17C19"" won't.

And for another file, "UniqueId:"7DF79D3B-9486-4031-86E5-BBDD9DC05D71"" will work but UniqueId:"{7DF79D3B-9486-4031-86E5-BBDD9DC05D71}" won't work.

Any advice on how to alert Microsoft to this issue? Not sure how to do this in the UI to get the result that will get support.

Comment: (The one with the {} characters is what had been working, I believe up until yesterday but with the holiday could have started sooner)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7160